# In R, how can I see the signatures for which a generic method is implemented?

Tags: r, generics, method-signature

Is there a function in R that finds all implemented signatures for a given generic function?

I am looking for something like:

```
findSignatures("myFunction")
```

> [1] "character"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to see the signatures, you can use the `showMethods` function:

```
showMethods("myFunction")
```